# Targeted voice sensing in noisy environment

Tags: sensor, sound, datalogger, acoustic-noise

My exercise, for my own interest and use, is exploring a way of measuring the relative volume of one person's voice when in conversation with a group of people.

My first idea entailed logging noise levels measured at a location reasonably equidistant from the speakers. The target speaker would push a button while talking and these periods would also be logged, giving fairly straightforward qualitative data, which is all that's needed.

However I would like to avoid the need for manually logging when the user is talking; I believe this would impede spontaneous conversation, and likely interfere with the user 'giving honest answers' i.e. 'performing' so the data would show what they expected or wanted it to show.

All I have come up with to get around this is some type of wearable vibration sensor that would detect vibrations in the throat, but I don't need some high-tech device used for detecting and measuring the movement of tectonic plates or strands of heart muscle.
.. A simple Speaking/Not Speaking trace is all I need.
Could something as simple as a piezoelectric transducer be enough?

Comment: Class 2 (ferroelectric) MLCCs are the cheapest vibration sensors. Albeit indeed rather bad and "not high-tech". As you can see, as with all such human-device-interfacing it is always a problem of mechanical attachment and interfacing rather than electrical engineering one.

Comment: I would record continuously and use the recorded amplitude to determine when someone is talking. Since you want to record multiple people at multiple locations, consider using an array of microphones to reduces the effect of position on amplitude and simplify distinguishing between multiple speakers.

Comment: Giving then several audio tracks with known 'owners' for simple comparison? Straightforward enough. Time to look into putting together a cluster of discrete shotgun mics - or rig my family with Lavaliers!